# How is the "rails new" implemented and where can I see it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that Rails source code is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails).

As far as I know, Rails new generates a bunch of directories and files. Where is the source code located for this command located?

Comment: Step 1: `which rails`. Step 2: Open that file. Step 3: Follow the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is it: [railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb)

It's called from `rails/railties/lib/rails/commands/application.rb`, which first parses the command-line args. It works by filling templates, which can be found here [railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates).

BTW, you can specify your own template for the app, e.g. in [Rails Girls](http://railsgirls.co.il/en/guides/app/create-app/app.html) we use

```
rails new railsgirls -m http://railsgirls.co.il/template.rb
```